# Optional bindings and references

Tags: swift

Can I somehow use optional binding as references? If yes, how can I do it?

The following code sorts the copy of `self.threadsInfo?.threads?`, not the original one.

```
if var threads = self.threadsInfo?.threads? {
            switch self.threadsSortType
            {
            case .Score:
                threads.sort {
                    $0.score > $1.score
                }
            case .Views:
                threads.sort {
                    $0.views > $1.views
                }
            case .PostsCount:
                threads.sort {
                    $0.postsCount > $1.postsCount
                }
            default:
                assert(false, "Unknown threads sort type")
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are value type so its being copied here:

```
var threads = self.threadsInfo?.threads?
```

You can assign sorted array back to original:

```
if var threads = self.threadsInfo?.threads? {
            switch self.threadsSortType
            {
            case .Score:
                threads.sort {
                    $0.score > $1.score
                }
            case .Views:
                threads.sort {
                    $0.views > $1.views
                }
            case .PostsCount:
                threads.sort {
                    $0.postsCount > $1.postsCount
                }
            default:
                assert(false, "Unknown threads sort type")
            }

            self.threadsInfo?.threads = threads
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can move the sorting logic to a separate function accepting a *non optional* array by reference:

```
func sort(inout threads: [MyThreadType]) {
    switch self.threadsSortType {
    case .Score:
        threads.sort {
            $0.score > $1.score
        }

    case .Views:
        threads.sort {
            $0.views > $1.views
        }

    case .PostsCount:
        threads.sort {
            $0.postsCount > $1.postsCount
        }

    default:
        assert(false, "Unknown threads sort type")
    }
}
```

And call like:

```
if self.threadsInfo?.threads != nil {
    sort(&self.threadsInfo!.threads!)
}
```

Value types are always passed by value (i.e. by copy). The only case where they can be passed by reference is to function/methods via the `inout` modifier.